# Desktop for Custom Space

Tags: repainting, finishing, desk

I had a space to put my workspace that is kind of unusual, very long, I had a desk built, but the finish on it is a joke. I went to Ikea to see if I could buy one of their custom desktops (prefinished) and just drop it in, but the max size was not long enough.

Here are some potential solutions:

- Get 2 pieces and connect them with dowels or something, then I will have a seam
- Get an IKEA piece and just have it end and then the top of the file cabinet would be exposed
- Have someone refinish this top, taking the time to build up a more durable version
- Have a new custom top done using prefinished material

The setup itself is a really good one.

The desk is like 80" wide I think? and max at IKEA was 72 or something like that, misses by 6 inches or so.

[image]

Comment: Or buy [sheet Formica](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=formica+sheets) (not already on backer board) and cut it to fit, and glue it down.

Comment: why not **refinish** the one you have?  How long is very long, what other space restrictions apply?  more info needed.

Comment: I put refinish as an option? The guy who did this should have done several coats of course but did not.

Comment: My bad, I do not think more coats would have stopped it form pealing. It was not prepped correctly,  It should have been striped or at least sanded well before applying paint on what looks to be a varnished surface. It should be stripped and sanded before you put a new finish on it.

Comment: The top edges were not flush to the edge so paint abrasion was to be expected. Whatever you choose this must be done.  Formica is a durable choice if done correctly